# Running pig local, UDF program cannot write files/folder: PriviledgedActionException

Tags: exception, hadoop, permissions, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

Newbie with Pig/hadoop..

Running pig at local.

```
java  -Xmx512m -Xmx1024m -cp $PIGDIR/pig.jar org.apache.pig.Main -Dpig.temp.dir=/tmp/$USER/$RANDOM -stop_on_failure -x  local script-buzz.pig
```

with my script.pig:

```
(...) 
buzz = FOREACH files GENERATE chiron.buzz.Honey(file, id) as buzz_file, id;
```

Trying to write a folder/file with my UDF raise:

```
[JobControl] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation - PriviledgedActionException as:felipehorta cause:org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist: file:/Users/felipehorta/dev/ufrj/pig/pig-buzz/output
```

the following code must (!) writes files that are consumed at the next LOAD.

jar works fine with: $ java -jar Pgm.jar *

```
(...)
public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    try{
        System.out.println(input.get(0).toString());
        BumbleBee b = new BumbleBee(input.get(0).toString());
        return b.writeRelation(input.get(1).toString());
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Failed to process input; error - " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public String writeRelation(String folder) throws IOException {
    try {
        // writing file!
        File output = new File("output/ERelation_" + folder +  ".txt");
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(output);
        String line = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        fw.append("YEAR;WORD;COUNT" + line);
        for (Integer year : buzzCandidates.keySet()) {
            Map<String, Long> wordCounts = buzzCandidates.get(year);
            for (String word : wordCounts.keySet()) {
                long value = wordCounts.get(word);
                if (value >= 3) {
                    fw.append(year + ";" + word.replace(" ", "_") + ";" + String.valueOf(value) + line);
                }
            }
        }
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
        return output.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(">>> ERROR!!\t" + e.getMessage());
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

I think it is about permission writing files with UDF, but I dont know where set permissions. Any help?

Thanks in advance, fellows!

Comment: Can you attach the pig-*-.log to show the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Error reads **Input path does not exist: file:/Users/felipehorta/dev/ufrj/pig/pig-buzz/output** Please check the pig script as to how the load is used.

```
relation = load '/Users/felipehorta/dev/ufrj/pig/pig-buzz/output' using ...
```

would be the correct way of doing it.

Not sure if this could be the exact reason. Would be great if you could post the scripts.